# Variable amounts of arguments in class

Tags: java, arguments

for a project I am doing, I have to create a class called BirdButton which has either 4 or 5 arguments in its constructor. It looks something like the following. Note animals is a separate class which is a picture of some birds. birdbutton will, depending on the input, highlight different birds in the image.

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class BirdButton extends EventButton
{
    public BirdButton(String n, int x, int y, Animals a){
     super(n);
     setLabel(n);
     setBounds(50,10,x,y);
     a.add(this);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    }
}
```

In another class I attempt to add the Buttons to the JFrame, however the number of agruments passed to the button is either 4 or 5. For this project the other class, driver, cannot be changed and looks like this

```
public class Driver {
    private JFrame win;
    private Animals animals = new Animals();
    private BirdButton nextBtn, enlargeBtn, shrinkBtn, moveToBtn;
    private JTextField field;

    public Driver() {
        win = new JFrame("Angry Animal Name Game");
        win.setBounds(100, 100, 600, 600);
        win.setLayout(null);
        win.setVisible(true);
        nextBtn = new BirdButton( "NEXT", 10, 10, animals);
        win.add(nextBtn, 0);
        enlargeBtn = new BirdButton( "ENLARGE", 10, 60, animals);
        win.add(enlargeBtn, 0);
        shrinkBtn = new BirdButton( "SHRINK", 10, 110, animals);
        win.add(shrinkBtn, 0);
        field = new JTextField();
        field.setBounds(10, 250, 100, 20);
        win.add(field, 0);
        moveToBtn = new BirdButton( "MOVETO", 10, 275, animals, field);
        win.add(moveToBtn, 0);
        win.add(animals, 0);
        animals.recenter();
        win.repaint();
    }
}
```

When I try to compile the code, I receive an error that the number of arguments differs in length and so it wont work. How do I code the BirdButton to accept either 4 or 5 inputs?

Thanks

Comment: Why can't you just make a second constructor that takes 5 arguments?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use an overloaded constructor:

```
public class BirdButton extends EventButton
{
    public BirdButton(String n, int x, int y, Animals a, JTextField field) {
        super(n);
        setLabel(n);
        setBounds(50,10,x,y);
        setField(field);
        a.add(this);
    }

    public BirdButton(String n, int x, int y, Animals a) {
        this(n, x, y, a, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you this made it work, but I don't really understand the concept behind creating the second constructor and the code within. Are you able to shed some light on the whole overloaded constructor concept?

Comment: @GeeBoughuski, it's just like method overloading. They both have the same name but accept different parameters. The second version calls the first version using the `this` keyword, passing `null` as the `field` value.

Comment: and word to the wise: don't use varargs, just asking for trouble and unmaintainable code